# How to refresh binding data in silverlight mvvm using NotificationObject

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding

i'm working on a textbox required TimeSpan value. the input content need to be validated and may in several different formats (for ex 1300 means 13:00). I do some work to check and convert it in viewmodel. but after that how can i refresh the text in textbox?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path= OpenHourFromText, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" ></TextBox>
```

OpenHourFromValue is a string property that i used for validation and data binding

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : NotificationObject{
        public string OpenHourFromText
                {
                    get
                    {
    //OpenHourFrom is a TimeSpan property that contain the value
                        if (OpenHourFrom != null)
                        {
                            return GetOpeningHourText(OpenHourFrom); //fomat the time
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                    set
                    {
//do validation and convert here. 1300 will be changed to 13:00 TimeSpan type
                        OpenHourFrom = ConvertToTimeSpan(value);  
                        RaisePropertyChanged("OpenHourFromText");
                    }
                }

        public TimeSpan OpenHourFrom { get; set; }

}
```

the viewmodel is inherit from Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel.NotificationObject

After i input 1300 in the textbox, the OpenHourFrom is updated. But the text of textbox is not changed to 13:00. why? please help, many thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When TextBox is setting some value it won't call get.The solution to this can be like replacing RaisePropertyChanged("OpenHourFromText") with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => RaisePropertyChanged("OpenHourFromText"));It will delay firing that event.

```
set 
   { 
    //do validation and convert here. 1300 will be changed to 13:00 TimeSpan type 
     OpenHourFrom = ConvertToTimeSpan(value);                                            
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => RaisePropertyChanged("OpenHourFromText"));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're raising a PropertyChange notification for the property `UpdateTimeText`, while your actual property name is `OpenHourFromText`

Change your `PropertyChange` notification to raise the notification for the correct property, and it should update for you.

Comment: sorry i paste the code by mistake, it is OpenHourFromText in my source code. But it didn't work for me.

Comment: @aiyagaze Does it work if you set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the binding? The default is `LostFocus`, meaning it will only update the source when focus is lost